# Navigation in react Web using a modal

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a job to do today and i'm looking for ideas or articles about a specific modal that i have to do.
I need to create a modal in React Web to navigate between 5 diferent components, but i dont know how can i do this, i have a modal but i dont know about the navigation based on state.
I want to do something like this :
https://web.skype.com/
If someone knows, pls help me :D

i have just the first modal body:

```
<ModalNavLogin>
 { i need to render and change components here}
</ModalNavLogin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i did a function with a label name:

```
function handleChangeComp(string) {
   if(!string) return;
   setComp(string);
}

Then i just use the string to render components:
{ com === stringName && <MyModalContent>}
```